# Is there anyway of changing legacy boot to UEFI boot without destroying whole partition?

Tags: boot, boot-partition

Windows 8.1 has been setup in legacy boot mode,it means it is MBR. But I want to chane it to UEFI boot mode which means GPT partition. Can I change in bios legacy boot mode to UEFI boot mode? Will my partitions and data will be destroyed?

Comment: You first have to convert your partitions to GPT.  Its possible to do this without data loss but it is extremely technical and isn't for the unexperienced.

Answer (score 0):

UEFI uses GPT partitions. [According to Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725671.aspx), you cannot change the partition scheme on Windows without data loss.

"You can change a disk from MBR to GPT partition style as long as the disk does not contain any partitions or volumes."

However, if you're feeling risky, [this website](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/convert-mbr-to-gpt-disk) suggests a couple of ways to convert to GPT without data loss. The easiest of these involves using a tool called "AOMEI Partition Assistant Lite Edition." Using this software, you should be able to just right click on the disk and select "Convert to GPT/MBR disk."

Comment: While I don't think you're spamming here, please be advised that AOMEI has a long pattern of spam posts here on Super User.